# how to get the count() from subquery in laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a foreach on Transactions Collection like this:

each transaction has many carts and each cart has many acceptedcarts.

```
@foreach($Transactions as $transaction)
 {{$transaction->whereHas('carts.acceptedcarts', function ($query) {$query->where('sended', false);})->count()}}
@endforeach
```

but it return all `acceptedcarts->where('sended',false)` not acceptedcarts of this particular transaction.

how can I get the `acceptedcarts->where('sended',false)->count()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, I use the `withCount()` on my controller like this :

```
$Transactions = Transaction::withCount(['acceptedcarts' => function ($q) {
            $q->where('sended', false);
        }])->get();
```

and in my blade I use the `acceptedcarts_count` property to achieve it.

```
@foreach($Transactions as $transaction)
   {{$transaction->acceptedcarts_count}}
@endforeach
```

and it's work!